# asp.net mvc radio button list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a list of radio buttons for a list of values in ASP.NET MVC. I am confused on how to write the model for the radio button list and the view to be displayed. I need to display a static list of values.

Can some please help.

Thanks.

Comment: you can bind selectlist items to radiobuttons too..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i'm implementing values on viewModel you can take it from model if you want

viewModel

```
    public class PropMgmtViewModel
{
    public Property Property { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public SelectList Cities { get; private set; }


    static Dictionary<int, string> CitiesDict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1 ,"Chicago"},
    { 2 ,"New York"},
    { 3 ,"Zimbabwe"},
};
    public PropMgmtViewModel()
    {
        Cities = new SelectList(CitiesDict, "Key", "Value");
    }
```

view code i also included the seleclist propert to show you how it's done

```
 @foreach (var radioitem in Model.Cities)
    {
        @radioitem.Text;
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Property.City, radioitem.Value);
    }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.City, Model.Cities,"Seciniz")
```